# Transpose a 2D vector matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Is there a way to find transpose a 2D vector matrix without allocating another 2D vector??

**Sample Testcase**

```
Input: matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Output: [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Code that I tried

```
class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        int i,j, n=matrix.size(),temp;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
                temp=matrix[i][j];
                matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i];
                matrix[j][i]=temp;
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Printed Output:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Expected Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 9
3 6 9
```

Edited:

New Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void transpose(vector<vector<int>>& mat, int n) {
        int i,j,temp;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
                temp=mat[i][j];
                mat[i][j]=mat[j][i];
                mat[j][i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    void rotate(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        int n=matrix.size(),i,j;
        transpose(matrix, n);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, just swap elements

Comment: Nope it does work the same way as 2D array matrix

Comment: Please check the edited question

Comment: No @paddy is right, swap the elements you need to move around e.g. std::swap(a[0][2],a[2][0]).

Comment: But that like again allocating a different 2D vector right?

Comment: No it will be done in place. By passing the matrix by reference to rotate you don't make a copy

Comment: Its still the same result, pls check the edited qsn now. I have added the new code I tried based on your approach

Comment: You're swapping every possible combination.  You should only traverse a single triangle either side of the diagonal.  _e.g._ `for (j = 0; j < i; j++)` <-- note `j < i` not `j < n`.  It would be very straight forward for you to work through this by hand on paper and work out how your swaps should go.  Also, use `std::swap` instead of the 3-line version you're doing.

Comment: Yes that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for **inplace**(Fixed space) || n*n matrix

```
class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        int i,j,n=matrix.size();
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            // Instead of j starting with 0 every time, its needs to start from i+1
            for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                swap(matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i]);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
            reverse(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that there's no point in starting the j-loop at `i` because that is on the diagonal.  Either use `i+1` or use the loop I suggested in the question comments.

Comment: that's a valid point